# Tensorflow get a percentage of input size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a working solution for this problem, but it seems extremely long winded. I was wondering what the "proper" way of achieving this is...

Suppose I have a tensor `a` with dimensions [?,5,...] (the trailing dimensions here are unimportant). At runtime, the first dimension could be anything, 100, 200, etc. depending on the size of the dataset passed by a feed dict.

Internally, I need to get a percentage of the dataset size (the first dimension) as an int. In normal numpy code, that would look something like:

```
def percentOfInputSize( data, percent = .5 ):
    return int( round( data.shape[0] * percent ) )
```

In tensorflow, the only way I have of achieving this is

```
def percentOfInputSize( data, percent = .5 ):
   rows = tf.shape(data)[0]
   return tf.cast( tf.round( tf.cast(rows, tf.float32) * percent ), tf.int32)
```

but that looks horrible. Is there a better way of computing this value?

Comment: That may be explicit, but is the right way. I would only consider the extra whitespace "looking horrible".

Comment: I do love me some whitespace

Comment: Can You Please post an answer so that I can accept it.